# Deleting multiple listitems from listcollection - only deletes half items

Tags: delete

I have an issue around using SPListItem.Delete. I am fetching some list items (less than 20) and looping through them using a for loop. In each iteration of the loop, I retrieve a SPListItem using SPListItemCollection.GetItemByID method. And then I execute a Delete(). However, it only deletes half the items.

Can some one please help?

Code follows:

```
 SPListItemCollection listItems = Get_Items();
                 for (int i=0; i<listItems.Count; i++)

            {
                SPListItem currentListItem = listItems.GetItemById(listItems[i].ID);

                currentListItem.Delete();

            }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post your code for us to see?

Comment: Done. code edited to the post. thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No errors, it consistently just deletes exactly half of what is in the listitemcollection. So if I have 20 start with it will delete 10, then it will delete 5, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to start from `i=listItems.Count-1` to avoid looping on items that already deleted!

```
for(int i=listItems.Count-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
          SPListItem currentListItem = ListName.Items[i];
          currentListItem .Delete();
     }
```

or

```
for(int i=listItems.Count-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
          SPListItem currentListItem = listItems.GetItemById(listItems[i].ID);
          currentListItem .Delete();
     }
```

Comment: didn't work. I get Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: changed it to i-- and >=0 and now working. Thanks Mohammed appreciate it.

for (int i = listItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Comment: Most welcome ;) the answer updated to be helpful fo future coming users